# Node.js - Distinguish between server connect and disconnect on 'connection' event

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a server in my Node.js application with `net.createServer`.
I add an event listener to the "connection"-event to be able to determine when a connection has been established. All well so far.

The problem is that when I disconnect it seems to trigger the "connection"-event again! And there is no "disconnect" event, so I don't know how to know if it is connected or disconnected!

```
const server = createServer({ allowHalfOpen: true }, (socket) => {
  this._socket.on("data", (buffer) => {
    // ...
  });

  this._socket.on("end", () => {
    // ...
});

server.on("connection", () => {
  console.log("Connected or Disconnected!")
});
```

How can I determine if the connection is established or ended?

I would like to avoid having a flag keeping track of the state if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my naive approach to this issue that seems to work is to use getConnections, which will increase on every connection event, and see if it is even or uneven to be able to determine if it is connected or disconnected:

```
server.on("connection", () => {
  server.getConnections((e, c) => {
    if (c % 2 === 0) {
      // Disconnected
    } else {
      // Connected
    }
  });
```

It does not feel like a good solution, but maybe good enough until someone can show me a better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
server.on("close", () => {
  console.log("Disconnected!")
});
```

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close

Answer (score 0):

Within the connection listening event, there is a listening event for disconnections:

```
var clients = [];
server.on('connection', (socket) => {

    // add client
    clients.push({id:15, name:'client15'}); 

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        // first search client and  remove
    });
});
```

Now the next question would be: how do I know which person disconnected?

The answer to this question is more than putting logic to the process and you can create a global variable for save client, when the person starts session or connects to the socket, it is registered in that variable and when it is disconnected it must be taken out of said variables, this is not ma than an example but there may be better ways.

Comment: The "disconnect" event doesn't exist on Socket